# How to nest modules in TypeScript so that consumers import a single object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, module, export

I want to write a TypeScript library so that it can be imported and consumed in the following way:

```
import {MyLibrary} from 'my-library';

MyLibrary.MyModule.MySubModule.myMethod();
```

What is the right way to do it?

I tried the following:

```
export module MyLibrary {
    export module MyModule {
        export {MySubModule} from './my-module/my-sub-module/MySubModule';
    }
}
```

but I get that `Export declarations are not permitted in a namespace`.

Comment: Treeshaking won't work if you wrote it like that.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating your comment? I'm not sure I understand it, sorry.

Comment: use namespace instead of module